# Linq filter distinct rows to datatable

Tags: linq, datatable

How am I able to pass the results from the below to a datatable, so I can display in a datagridview?

```
        var query = from r in DtSet.Tables["tblCharge"].AsEnumerable()
                    select new
                        {invoice = r.Field<string>("InvNo"),
                         type = r.Field<string>("EorD")};
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done by

```
dataGridView.DataSource = query.ToList();
```